# HTML_SAFE allow everything except <span style="font-size: TAG

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html-safe

How do I disallow font size change in html_safe rails 3

I have here a truncated description of an article, and I want to disallow big font sizes in display mode when the user inputs a big font size using tinymce editor

```
= truncate(event.description.html_safe, :length => 110, :omission => "...")
```

How can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to use the `sanitize` helper before marking it as html_safe. Unfortunately for you, in this case, the blacklist functionality has been removed, so you will need to list literally all of the attributes you do want, in addition to the defaults. It may be easier to use a regex to remove the attribute in question.

Also, for what it's worth, `raw(event.description)` does the same as `event.description.html_safe`, but will not blow up on a nil value (not sure what your validation rules are), so it is generally preferred.

**Edit:**

Sanitize example usage (from http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.8/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper/sanitize ):

```
truncate( raw( sanitize(event.description, :tags => %w(table tr td), :attributes => %w(id class style) ) ), :length => 110, :omission => "...")
```

Note: Truncating HTML like that can lead to some weird and hard-to-track-down errors, by creating invalid HTML because of cut-off end tags.

Comment: Thanks I'd rather choose raw (data) . Btw I still dont know how to put whitelist sorry